# SSIS errors Perform Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I am trying to run a SSIS project and new to SSIS. But i am getting 14 errors  like

```
Error   1   Validation error. DFT - Generate XML - AU: DFT - Generate XML - AU: The component metadata for "component "Template - Format to XML" (156)" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.      XMLC_Seafolly.dtsx  0   0   

Error   2   Validation error. DFT - Generate XML - SG & US: DFT - Generate XML - SG & US: The component metadata for "component "Template - Format to XML" (156)" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.    XMLC_Seafolly.dtsx  0   0   

Error   13  Validation error. DFT - Generate XML - AU SSIS.Pipeline: The component metadata for "component "Template - Format to XML" (156)" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.     XMLC_Seafolly.dtsx  0   0
```

I have installed SSIS on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am not sure what is the problem can anyone guide me please how to run an existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-performupgrade.html

That write up is everything you need. And I always recommend that you run full Windows updates.

Also a duplicate of question answered here, though not as completely as the above link. @ [Cause of SSIS Custom Dataflow Component Error - Cannot be upgraded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194532/cause-of-ssis-custom-dataflow-component-error-cannot-be-upgraded)

I do not advise installing SQL Server 2008 R2 as many shops are moving away from it in favor of 2012.

My opinion (regardless if this is a personal installation or a business one) would be to **uninstall** SQL Server 2008 R2 and reinstall SQL Server 2012 with all the features i.e. everything but the SharePoint boxes listed here: [image]

If you "must" use SQL Server 2008 R2, then revisit the installation you did, as you probably missed the client tools backwards compatibility box.